# Why browser instances not getting close/quit after execution in Selenium and TestNG?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I am trying to automate few test cases from different test cases in sequential manner. i.e. one after another test class execution.

In some of cases, web application is not getting closed/quit. i.e. driver instance not closing/quitting. I am trying to quit/close driver in @AfterClass method as well as test class level as well but its not working in both cases.

In TestNG Suite results, its showing as its tried to executed but webdriver instances are NOT closed and new webpage instance is open.

[image]

For reference I have shared code for 1st two test classes.

Please check below snippet for code:

```
package managers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import enums.EnvironmentType;

public class VMSBaseDriver {
    public WebDriver driver;
//  private static DriverType driverType;
    private static EnvironmentType environmentType;
    private static final String CHROME_DRIVER_PROPERTY = "webdriver.chrome.driver";
    private static final String IE_DRIVER_PROPERTY = "webdriver.ie.driver";

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Parameters("browserName")

    @BeforeClass

    public void initialize(String browser) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        environmentType = FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getEnvironment();
//      driverType = FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getBrowser();

        switch (environmentType) {
        case LOCAL:
            System.out.println("(In Local) Selected environment from config :: " + environmentType);
            if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
                System.setProperty(CHROME_DRIVER_PROPERTY,
                        FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getDriverPath() + "/chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("internetexplorer")) {

                System.setProperty(IE_DRIVER_PROPERTY,
                        FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getDriverPath() + "/IEDriverServer.exe");
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
                        true);
                capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_USE_PRE_PROCESS_PROXY, true);
                capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
                capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS, false);
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);

            }

            if (FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getBrowserWindowSize())
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(
                    FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getImplicitlyWait(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            // driver.get(FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getApplicationUrl());
            driver.get("http://" + getIPAddress());
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            break;

        case REMOTE:
            System.out.println("(In Remote) Selected environment from config :: " + environmentType);
            if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

                FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
                FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

                profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
                profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
                profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 0);
                firefoxOptions.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://172.20.1.24:4444/wd/hub"), firefoxOptions);
            } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {

                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
                options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
                options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
                capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");

                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://172.20.1.24:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("internetexplorer")) {

                DesiredCapabilities iecapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                iecapabilities.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
                iecapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
                        true);
                iecapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
                iecapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
                iecapabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
                iecapabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
                iecapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "");
                iecapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.LOG_LEVEL, "DEBUG");

                iecapabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);

                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://172.20.1.24:4444/wd/hub"), iecapabilities);

            }

            if (FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getBrowserWindowSize())
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(
                    FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getImplicitlyWait(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("http://" + getIPAddress());
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            break;
        }

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void TeardownTest() {

        driver.quit();

    }

    public String getIPAddress() {

        InetAddress IP = null;
        try {
            IP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            // System.out.println("IP of my system is := " + IP.getHostAddress());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return IP.getHostAddress();
    }

    public By extendedLocator(String locString, String value)

    {

        return By.xpath(String.format(locString, value));

    }

}
```

ViewTest Class

```
package testCases;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;

import managers.ExtentReportTestManager;
import managers.VMSBaseDriver;
import pageObjects.CamerasAndEncodersPage;
import pageObjects.MonitoringPage;
import pageObjects.ViewsPage;

public class ViewsTest extends VMSBaseDriver {

    public MonitoringPage monitoringPage;
    public ViewsPage viewsPage;
    CamerasAndEncodersPage camerasAndEncodersPage;
    public String[] Servers;

    @BeforeClass
    public void init() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        monitoringPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, MonitoringPage.class);
        viewsPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, ViewsPage.class);
        Servers = viewsPage.getServersList();

        driver.navigate().to("http://" + Servers[0]);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        viewsPage.SignIn();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        viewsPage.WaitUntilLoadingBlockAppears();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        viewsPage.WaitUntilLoadingBlockDisappears();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        viewsPage.GoToViewsPageFromLanding();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        viewsPage.GoToViewsPage();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    
    /*
     * @AfterMethod public void browserCategory(Method method) {
     * ExtentReportTestManager.startTest(method.getName()).assignCategory(((
     * RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getBrowserName().toUpperCase());
     * 
     * }
     */

    @Test
    public void AddNewViewTest(Method method) throws Exception {
        //logger = report.startTest("AddNewViewTest");
        ExtentReportTestManager.startTest(method.getName()).assignCategory(((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getBrowserName().toUpperCase());

        int viewsCount = viewsPage.GetViewsSize();
        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Click on New button");
        viewsPage.ClickOnNewButton();

        String viewName = "ViewName" + viewsPage.GetRandomDigit(0, 10000);
        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Input name " + viewName + " in name field");
        viewsPage.InputIntoNameField(viewName);

        String remarks = "Remarks for " + viewName;
        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Input remarks " + remarks + " in remarks field");
        viewsPage.InputIntoRemarksField(remarks);

        int layoutSize = viewsPage.GetLayoutSize();
        int random = viewsPage.GetRandomDigit(0, layoutSize);
        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Select layout ");
        viewsPage.ClickOnLayoutByIndex(random);

        int viewSize = viewsPage.GetLayoutViewSize();
        int resourcesSize = viewsPage.GetResourcesSize();
        int rand = viewsPage.GetRandomDigit(1, viewSize);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Drag " + rand + " resources ");
        for (int i = 0; i < rand; i++) {
            int viewIndex = viewsPage.GetRandomDigit(0, viewSize);
            int resIndex = viewsPage.GetRandomDigit(0, resourcesSize);
            String viewId = viewsPage.GetViewIDByIndex(viewIndex);
            String resourceId = viewsPage.GetResourcesIDByIndex(resIndex);
            viewsPage.DragAndDropCameraToView(resourceId, viewId);
        }

        int fullViewSize = viewsPage.GetFullViewsSize();
        int audioViewsSize = viewsPage.GetAudioViewsSize();
        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Press Save button");
        viewsPage.PressSaveButton();

        String viewNameSaved = viewsPage.GetViewName();
        String viewRemarksSaved = viewsPage.GetRemarksText();
        int fullViewSizeSaved = viewsPage.GetFullViewsSize();
        int audioViewsSizeSaved = viewsPage.GetAudioViewsSize();

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that view name is equals to inputed");
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(viewNameSaved, viewName);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that view remarks is equals to inputed");
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(viewRemarksSaved, remarks);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that layout has " + fullViewSize + "resources");
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(fullViewSizeSaved, fullViewSize);
//        Assert.assertEquals(audioViewsSizeSaved,audioViewsSize);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Refresh page ");
        viewsPage.Refresh();
        // int viewsCount = viewsPage.GetViewsSize();
        int viewsCountAfterRefresh = viewsPage.GetViewsSize();
        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that new view is added ");
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(viewsCountAfterRefresh, viewsCount + 1);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Click on " + viewName + " view");
        viewsPage.ClickOnViewByName(viewName);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        String viewNameRefreshed = viewsPage.GetViewName();
        String viewRemarksRefreshed = viewsPage.GetRemarksText();
        int fullViewSizeRefreshed = viewsPage.GetFullViewsSize();
        int audioViewsSizeRefreshed = viewsPage.GetAudioViewsSize();

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that view name is equals to inputed after refresh");
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(viewNameRefreshed, viewName);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that view remarks is equals to inputed after refresh");
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(viewRemarksRefreshed, remarks);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that layout has " + fullViewSize + "resources after refresh");
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(fullViewSizeRefreshed, fullViewSize);
//        Assert.assertEquals(audioViewsSizeRefreshed,audioViewsSize);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Go to Monitoring page");
        viewsPage.GoToMonitoringPage();

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Input into filter field");
        monitoringPage.FilterField(viewName);

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that new view is present in Monitoring Resources list");
        boolean viewIsExist = monitoringPage.VerifyThatResourceIsExist(viewName);
        AssertJUnit.assertTrue(viewIsExist);
    }

    

}
```

WebPageTest class

```
package testCases;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;

import managers.ExtentReportTestManager;
import managers.VMSBaseDriver;
import pageObjects.MonitoringPage;
import pageObjects.WebPagesPage;

public class WebPagesTest extends VMSBaseDriver {


    public MonitoringPage monitoringPage;
    public WebPagesPage webPagesPage;
    public String[] Servers;

    /*
     * @AfterMethod public void browserCategory(Method method) {
     * ExtentReportTestManager.startTest(method.getName())
     * .assignCategory(((RemoteWebDriver)
     * driver).getCapabilities().getBrowserName().toUpperCase());
     * 
     * }
     */

    @BeforeClass
    public void init() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        monitoringPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, MonitoringPage.class);
        webPagesPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, WebPagesPage.class);
        Servers = webPagesPage.getServersList();
        webPagesPage.SignIn();
        webPagesPage.WaitUntilLoadingBlockAppears();
        webPagesPage.WaitUntilLoadingBlockDisappears();
        webPagesPage.GoToWebPagesPageFromLanding();

        /*
         * driver.navigate().to("http://" + Servers[0]); try{
         * driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); }catch(Exception a){}
         * 
         * webPagesPage.WaitUntilLoadingBlockAppears();
         * webPagesPage.WaitUntilLoadingBlockDisappears();
         * webPagesPage.GoToWebPagesPage();
         */
    }

    @Test
    public void AddNewWebPageTest(Method method) throws InterruptedException {
        // logger = report.startTest("AddNewWebPageTest");
        
        
        ExtentReportTestManager.startTest(method.getName())
         .assignCategory(((RemoteWebDriver)
         driver).getCapabilities().getBrowserName().toUpperCase());

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Click on new button");
        webPagesPage.ClickOnNewButton();

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that Save button is disabled");
        AssertJUnit.assertFalse(webPagesPage.SaveButtonIsEnabled());

        ExtentReportTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Check that Cancel button is enabled");
        AssertJUnit.assertTrue(webPagesPage.CancelButtonIsEnabled());
    }

    

}
```

TestNG.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Test Suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="reporter.BaseListener" />
    </listeners>



    <test name="R121 Internet Explorere Execution"  thread-count="2" >
        <parameter name="browserName" value="internetexplorer" />
        <classes>
            <class name="testCases.ViewsTest" />
            <class name="testCases.WebPagesTest" />
            <class name="testCases.AddCameraManually" />
            <class name="testCases.AudioChannelsElementsTest" />
            <class name="testCases.AudioChannelsTest" />
            <class name="testCases.CamerasAndEncodersElementsTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add alwaysRun = true in @AfterClass annotation. like @AfterClass(alwaysRun=true).

If your test classes are independent of each other then it is good to use separate session for each test class. In this case you have to write @AfterClass method in each of test class to close individual session.